# Android - Unlock A Button Every X hours

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I Want to every time A user Clicks Some Button, The Button Deactivate For X hours, 
How Can I Do this?

if i just get the current time and next time from android device the user can cheat.

Comment: You could use the code of a basic alarm manager. First convert the X hours into time in milliseconds and inside the pending intent of the alarm manager, pass this value. On triggering of the pending intent just activate your button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the current time from API. [TimezoneDb](http://timezonedb.com/api) provides a free API:

When you wanna **deactivate** the button.
1) call the api get the time.
2) calculate the deactivation time by adding X hours.
3) save the time in shared Pref or db.

for **activating** it again
1) call api get the time.
2) compare time with saved time.

Comment: could you tell me how to use it?

Comment: check edit. and i guess TimezoneDb has clear documentation regarding api. if you still got daubt please ask.

Comment: Why do you need an API when Sytem.currentTimeInMilli() from java do the job ? But I prefere this idea, using a file or db to save the value even if the app crash, is killed, ... Alarm manager could be stop on sleep mode. EDIT : oups, didn't read the sheat part !

Comment: yeah that would do the job. but what if user changes the system time?

Comment: My apologie, I 've edit my comment, I didin't read this line. But this won't work if you don't have connection by the way. So the user might be stuck. It's is possible to recover the running time, can't remember how but it's a good trick

Comment: no worries. That is developer's call. how much security he wants. if you prefer with system time then that's fine. its just added option so code doesn't get hacked.